# Regex global match for Nodejs not working

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, twitter, express

I've tried this a million times and have searched EVERYWHERE! I cannot get this to work. 
I'm trying to extract the text of a tweet and look for a global match it only works when it matches it absolutely, but not if I add a word next to it. FYI I'm trying to do this in NodeJS.

ex:

```
var userTweet = tweet.text;
var gold = userTweet.match(/#gold/g);
console.log(gold);

console.log(userTweet);

if (userTweet == gold) {

        console.log('got it'); // only grabs it if it exactly matches the tweeted string
    }
    else {
        console.log('not getting it'); // if any other word besides 'gold' is present         doesn't work at all
    }
});
```

I'd like to add that I'm writing my code within the Twit stream.

and placed inside this function:

```
stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) { 


}
```

I'm basically expecting to track a key word and a specific user. But when I try to track a specific word, it overrides the user I want to track and tracks every user that uses that key word.

--- for anyone facing the same problem I ended up just using the twitter-text module. Although it has it's issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp like `/#gold.*?\b/g` instead:

```
> '#gold'.match(/#gold.*?\b/g)
[ '#gold' ]
> '#gold #asdf #golden'.match(/#gold.*?\b/g)
[ '#gold', '#golden' ]
> 'yay #gold #golddigger woohoo!'.match(/#gold.*?\b/g)
[ '#gold', '#golddigger' ]
```

You may also want to add `/i` to the modifiers so you can find `#GOLD`, `#GoLd`, etc.

Comment: yeah this doesn't work either I'm starting to think that it's Twitter that is limiting me from doing this. I'm trying to do it the regex way because I'm not able to 'follow' and 'track' one specific user. The 'track' parameter takes precedent over 'follow'.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" Maybe you can add to your original question some example inputs and expected outputs to help clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: when I type "#gold" it sees that, but when I type "#gold suubve" it doesn't see it at all. I've edited my question.

Comment: I got to work I needed to parse the tweet data I was getting. Twitter-text is a good module for this. There are a bunch of others available too!